# Update OpenGTS to GoogleMaps V3

Tags: google-maps-api-3, gps, google-maps-api-2

I am working on [OpenGTS](http://opengts.sourceforge.net/) 2.5.0 currently.
By default the system is using the OpenLayers as map provider.
I have to change it to use the GoogleMap.
It works fine in Google Maps Api V2 but I must change it to api V3.

I have search through the web and this site and follow the ways accordingly such as create a GoogleMapsV3.js, change config.conf and etc.

However, the instruction is always unclear and still I failed to make the changes.

I would be very grateful if someone can give a clear instruction.

---

It persists to show up the map with google maps api v2 even after i put in the GoogleMapsV3.js.
I view the code source after I run the web. It shows this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var GOOGLE_API = "2";
var GOOGLE_API_V2 = true;
......
</script>`
```

I can't locate in the coding, where to change it to use GOOGLE API V3

Comment: You should be a bit more specific as to what your exact problems are. If you're getting error messages, post them. It's impossible to guess what your issues are, and a full list of instructions would just duplicate the tutorials you already followed. Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: Thank you for your response.
Updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

1. Edit src/org/opengts/war/maps/jsmap/GoogleMaps.java  at line 113

> ```
> private String apiVersion   = "3";
> ```

1. Edit private.xml - remove "key" line

> ```
> <MapProvider name="googleMaps" 
>     active="${Domain.MapProvider.active=true}"
>     class="org.opengts.war.maps.jsmap.GoogleMaps"
>     rtPropPrefix="Domain.MapProvider.">
> ```